# Problema con mysqli y php, solo me guarda un dato

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Lo que pasa es que tengo el siguiente código en el cual me guarda solo 1 registro en la base de datos, luego de eso me aparece "error de registro" que yo indique que saliera en dado caso que los datos no se guarden correctamente.

Lo raro es que si borro este registro de la base de datos, me acepta nuevamente uno, pero más que eso no. ¿Alguien que tenga la respuesta?

Conexión:

```
<?php

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","sistema"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}?>
```

Formulario:

```
<form name="nuevo_usuario" method="POST" action="guarda_usuario.php">
    <table width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20"><b>Usuario</b></td>
            <td width="30"><input type="text" name="usuario" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Password</b></td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Email</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" name="eviar" value="Registrar" /></center></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Código de registro:

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
    
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
    
$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, contrasenia, email) VALUES ('$usuario','$password','$email')";
    
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guardar usuario</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>    
            
            <?php if($resultado>0){ ?>
                <h1>Usuario Guardado</h1>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <h1>Error al Guardar Usuario</h1>       
            <?php   } ?>        
            
            <p></p> 
            
            <a href="index.php">Regresar</a>
            
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Talvez es un error al crear tu tabla SQL, el id o clave primaria no está marcada como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y por eso al momento de insertar un nuevo registro te retorna un false ya que las claves primarias no se pueden repetir. Pero para saber si estoy en lo correcto, podrías aumentar el código SQL de tu tabla usuarios

Comment: por lo que veo mi codigo sql nada mas dice, select * from usuarios y ya, y si tengo una primaria que es el id, no se si tengo el incremento

Comment: si era eso, jamas me hubiera dado cuenta y tal vez fue un poco tonto, disculpa por la molestia....

Comment: No hay problema, siempre nos pasa. Es como el ; en el código jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega un índice único (autoincrement) a la tabla (p.ej. 'id') y modifica tu consulta así:

```
$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (id,usuario, contrasenia, email)
     VALUES (null,'$usuario','$password','$email')";
```